# Android Studio create new activity requires fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been away from **Android** app creation for quite a while and has just recently begun my new App.

Now i thought i would test out this new **Android Studio** and therefore downloaded it.

When i started my project it asked for a `fragment` and i wasnt quite sure what it ment (i know what a `fragment` is!).

When it started the project i had a `activity_main` and a `fragment_main`. And now every time i want to create a new `activity` it requires me to create an additional `fragement`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening (maybe ive missed something).

Comment: i never did get an answer to this question. only a downvote :S

Comment: upvote, i confused with this too. what is fragment? can i not use use it?

Comment: I observe the same behaviour when adding an activity to an existing project; it always adds the activity and a layout and a fragment layout. I guess the fragment comes in by default either because the add activity part is not yet finished (not having the option to choose whether to make the fragment or not) or because google tries to encourage us to use the fragments more in out design.

Comment: I've the same question... maybe someone have an answer since december?

Comment: Quite often, you want just a basic activity for testing and not ten thousand fragment layout files and other junk. It's stupid they removed simple Activity with just one layout. Now I have to create it myself every time...

Answer (score 5):

Fragments are part of Google's UI design [philosophy](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design) since Honeycomb (see embedded link).

If you would like to work around the default activity template in Android Studio, then check out this blog [post](http://google-android-studio.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-non-frame-layout-with-android.html).

Answer (score 3):

To add an Activity without a fragment, select `File`->`New`->`Activity`->`Empty Activity`